# Does a Service stops its worker thread when the service itself is stopped?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have two services in my app.
First Service listens for a broadcast from System.
Based on it the first service makes decision whether to start or stop a Second Service.
Now my Second service performs some network tasks by starting a separate worker thread.

My question is : when I will stop the 2nd service from 1st service, definitely onDestroy() will be called for 2nd Service, but would it also stop its worker thread or the worker thread will keep going until it finishes ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created the `Thread` yourself, then no, it won't be stopped automatically. You're responsible for killing it in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: So what is the way of killing it ?

Comment: @Ankit Generally, calling `interrupt()` and then checking for `isInterrupted()`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: @Ankit Also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html -- probably simpler to understand (although it suggests basically the same thing).